# How to access the last element added in Django Rest API?

Tags: python, json, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am creating my own portfolio website and created Django rest API. I want to extract or GET data of the last user. so what can I do in the following code?

[>> Here in image last user and its id is rounded, whose data I have to retrieve <<](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUoTz.jpg)

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import viewsets, filters
from sample.api.serializers import UserSerializer

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

def viewname(request, user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    return ('hii :',user)

viewname()
```

Comment: last user data is not LIFO pattern there is nothing going out here

Comment: `viewname()` you dont call views like this that has to be mapped with a url and run it by postman or any module that sends http request

Comment: ok ok, it's my mistake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First last user data is not LIFO pattern there is nothing going out here

If you want to get the last record into the user table you can get it by

`User.objects.last()` 
You dont need `user_id` either because you dont know last user_id here
and you have to serialize this record and use `Response` in django rest framework  to send like this

```
 from rest_framework.response import Response

 def viewname(request):
    last_user = User.objects.last()
    serializer = UserSerializer(last_user)
    return Response(serilizer.data,status=200)
```

Comment: You can either `last_user.username` or `User.objects.values('username').last()` If it helped you can accept it as an answer